# Kawasaki ZZR600 Model D3 - where is the fuel filter?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, kawasaki, fuel-filter

I've been looking for the location of the fuel filter.

At first I thought it might not have one, and only the Model E ZZR's have one, because there seems to be no explicit mention of it or diagram in the Haynes Manual. It seems to me that it would be somewhere between the fuel tank and the carburettor, but I can't find it. A Model E also has a fuel pump, which the Model D does not, so could it be something to do with that?

On the other hand, it does seem to have one, because you can buy them, such as here:
http://www.patternparts.net/p-Kawasaki_ZZR_600_Fuel_Filter_93_05-33376.aspx

Comment: New MC Chatroom    http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46288/motorcycle-diaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with your model, but sometimes they are located on the petcock, inside the tank.

Edit: I cannot find old diagrams, but at least ZZR600's some years younger than yours seem to have had those. Oldest diagram I could find at the moment: http://www.motosport.com/SE/motorcycle/oem-parts/KAWASAKI/2003/ZZR600/FUEL-TANK

Comment: Inside the tank? Oh man! No wonder I couldn't find it!